# Complete definition of special functions in Mathematica

Tags: special-functions

How can one display the actual integral involved in special functions like this

**MarcumQ[2, a, b]**

in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 2):

```
?? MarcumQ
```

Then click on the `>>` to go to the reference page.  Then open the **Details** panel to see:

$Q_m(a,b) = \int\limits_b^\infty x \left( {x \over a}\right)^{m-1} I_{m-1}(a x) Exp[- {1 \over 2} (a^2 + x^2)]\ dx$

Comment: When I type in mathematica: ?? MarcumQ ;
Mathematica shows:
MarcumQ[m,a,b] gives Marcum's Q function Subscript[Q, m](a,b).
MarcumQ[m,a,Subscript[b, 0],Subscript[b, 1]] gives Marcum's Q function Subscript[Q, m](a,Subscript[b, 0])-Subscript[Q, m](a,Subscript[b, 1]). >>

Comment: I prefer pressing F1.

Answer (score 0):

To get your Integral(s), You can use Wolfram|Alpha, see [Wolfram|Alpha Integration](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframAlphaIntegration.html), see also [How can I get all the results from a Wolfram | Alpha query?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/how-can-i-get-all-the-results-from-a-wolfram-alpha-query),

[image]

You ca also use http://www.wolframalpha.com/

[image]