# Converting WolframAlpha Output to Markdown

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, boxes

I am calling Wolfram Alpha using WolframScript. That is, I can't display all the beauty that is inserted into Wolfram Mathematica Notebook. Let's say I execute a line like this:

```
result = WolframAlpha["Weather in Saratov", "PodInformation"];
```

There are tables in the results. For example this one:

```
table = {{"WeatherStationInformation:WeatherData",1}, "Content"} /. result
```

[image]

If I look at the full form of this table, I see that it is a cumbersome expression that is only handled properly in the Mathematica UI, since it consists of *Boxes*. My question is if there is an easy way to convert the results from Wolfram Alpha to a more primitive form, given that it was a table/text/list/group of elements/graph/picture/ picture

- picture ->
- table -> |cl1|col2|...
- list -> * item1
- ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easiest way is to make use:

1. Pod ComputableData - see how [**HERE**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20802/13)
2. MathJax in markdown

So getting the data from

```
podDATA=WolframAlpha["Weather in Saratov",
    {{"WeatherStationInformation:WeatherData",1},"ComputableData"},
    PodStates->{"WeatherStationInformation:WeatherData__Show metric"}];
```

you then use TeXForm:

```
Grid[podDATA,Alignment->Left]//TeXForm
```

to get literally the result below working in markdown:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
 \text{name} & \text{UWPP} \\
 \text{relative position} & \text{186 km NNW} \\
 \text{relative elevation} & 41\text{m} \\
 \text{local time} & \text{11:07:03 am UTC+04  $|$  Thursday, February 8, 2024} \\
 \text{local sunlight} & \{\text{sun is above the horizon},\{\text{azimuth: 149${}^{\circ}$  (SSE)},\text{altitude:
   18${}^{\circ}$  ()}\}\} \\
\end{array}$$

Right-click on the above table and you will see that it is not an image but MathJax. I used this code in this post editor and this is the output of `TeXForm` besides `$$...$$`:

```
$$\begin{array}{ll}
 \text{name} & \text{UWPP} \\
 \text{relative position} & \text{186 km NNW} \\
 \text{relative elevation} & 41\text{m} \\
 \text{local time} & \text{11:07:03 am UTC+04  $|$  Thursday, February 8, 2024} \\
 \text{local sunlight} & \{\text{sun is above the horizon},\{\text{azimuth: 149${}^{\circ}$  (SSE)},\text{altitude:
   18${}^{\circ}$  ()}\}\} \\
\end{array}$$
```

Perhaps not super ideal. After some effort you could write parser to get the format of true markdown table:

- https://www.codecademy.com/resources/docs/markdown/tables
- https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Or there are tools that do it for you if you search for: *tex to markdown converter*.

Answer (score 4):

1. convert to Latex
2. save to file, say `A.tex`
3. use `pandoc -s A.tex -o A.md` to convert to markedown
4. test using online tool gives

[image]

```
result = WolframAlpha["Weather in Saratov", "PodInformation"];
mma = {{"WeatherStationInformation:WeatherData", 1}, "Content"} /.   result
TeXForm[mma]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The Latex is

```
\begin{array}{ll}
 \text{name} & \text{UWPP} \\
 \text{relative position} & 116\thickspace \text{mi} \text{NNW}\text{  }(\text{from }\text{center of Saratov}) \\
 \text{relative elevation} & 135 \text{feet} (\text{above} \text{center of Saratov}) \\
 \text{local time} & 11:10:59 \text{am} \text{UTC+04}\text{  $|$  }\text{Thursday, February 8, 2024} \\
 \text{local sunlight} & 
\begin{array}{l}
 \text{sun}\text{ is}\text{ above the horizon} \\
 \text{azimuth: }150{}^{\circ}\text{  }(\text{SSE})\text{  $|$  }\text{altitude: }18{}^{\circ}\text{  }() \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
```

Copy the above to plain textfile, say A.tex, Make sure to add `$$` and close everything with `$$`.

Use Latex to markdown converter. see [latex-to-markdown-converter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341899/latex-to-markdown-converter)

```
pandoc -s A.tex -o A.md
```

Test `A.md` using any markdown editor such as https://dillinger.io/  but there are others.

[image]

but notice that some styling is lost. Such as frames and such.